# wget ftp connection and download multiple connections

Tags: linux, command-line, ftp, centos, wget

I am using this command to transfer files:

```
wget -r --user="user@login" --password="Pa$$wo|^D" ftp://server.com/
```

Is it possible to download the increased number of connection?

Comment: Are you asking about downloading in parallel?

Comment: or do you mean a progress meter? In any case, this Q is not the scope of programming Qs suitable for StackOverflow. You can use the `flag` link at th bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it to http://superuser.com . Good luck.